# How to make Country-State-City like search in elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make dependent search like when user type country and select country then on next dropdown/text search result would be from that particular Countries state, after selecting state on next text search would only based on that selected state. can anyone help to achieve this kind thing via elastic search.

i am new to elastic Search  and i had basic idea of it, but didn't get idea how to do this kind of stuff where i need to search from child and feel data like map

Answer (score 0):

Fist, it is important to understand how Elasticsearch store its data. You can find this kind of info here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/documents-indices.html

So, basically what you need is build a query with two must terms.

1. One for the object type (Country, State, etc).
2. Other for the name ("Los Angeles", "Massachussets", etc). If you want a autocomplete feature you could add a wildcard query in your list. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Obs: When you store your State object do not forget to store the Country name together. Since Elasticsearch is non relational you have to have Country name indexed in the State document.

Hope that it helps

Comment: First of all thanks for answering , now i get bit clear vision. if you ever work with mongo then you have face situation where you need to populate other collection data from object id . that type of thing i want to try to achieve using  mongoosastic but not able to do it .

if you ever work with it then please guide on that , it's really helpful